# Count number of table rows between two specific rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
<table>
  <tr id="parent_1">
    <td>Parent 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>Child 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>Child 2</td>
  </tr>
  ...
  <tr id="parent_2">
    <td>Parent2</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

How can I find the number of child rows between parent_1 and parent_2 using jQuery?

Edit: Sorry, didn't make it clear that this is just an example, the table could contain any number of parent rows, and any number of child rows

Comment: Chatuman's solution is the best compromise between brevity and performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will get you what you want

```
var childCount = ($('#parent_2').get(0).rowIndex - $('#parent_1').get(0).rowIndex) - 1;
```

Comment: +1 excellent! but why bother with intermidiaries? Hit the API directly: document.getElementById('parent_2').rowIndex - document.getElementById('parent_1').rowIndex - 1;

Comment: Nice answer. Plus, @Vlad is right: jQuery gives you nothing in this case.

Comment: +1 Vlad's comment! Of course this assumes there are no other rows in between which are neither ‘parent’ nor ‘child’, which is probable but the question's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 11):

This:

```
$('#parent_1 ~ .child:not(#parent_2 ~ *)').size()
```

Translation: match all elements of class `child` that are a sibling of, and come *after*, `#parent_1`, but not those that are a sibling of and come after `#parent_2`.

Comment: This was what I was hoping someone would think of.  Thanks for teaching me something! ;)

Comment: @Vlad: jQuery doesn't use XPATH.

Comment: It's a CSS 3 selector, not XPath, but your point stands—this is probably not the most efficient solution.

Comment: @crescentfres - I stand corrected, sorry, I had Prototype in mind; but the selector above will still do an order of magnitude more work (i.e. calls to the DOM API) than Chatuman's solution according to the jQuery source code. :)

Comment: @Miles, sorry, my mind was at Prototype which *will* attempt to use the browser's built-in xpath support (document.evaluate functionality)

Comment: If I weren't dealing with a table with millions of rows, (which you wouldn't be doing 99.9% of the time unless you want to bombard users w/ data) I would still rather use this solution.  I probably will want to do something with those rows later, and it's easier to read if you know jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

First idea that came to mind.  I'm sure there's some elaborate way to select the elements in question, (meaning you would just have to do $(selector).length) but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

```
var doCount = false;
var numberOfChildren = 0;

$('tr').each(function(i){
    if($(this).is("#parent_2"))
        doCount = false;

    if(count)
        numberOfChildren++;

    if($(this).is("#parent_1"))
        doCount = true;
});
```

Comment: -1 - Poor performance; scans all rows in the table, even if you have 1 million and are only going to end up counting two (which happen to be at the end of the table.)

Comment: How often are you going to have so many rows that counting them kills performance?  I agree there are better solutions, but I wouldn't worry about O(n) too much in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is probably to count manually. It'll be faster because you can break off when you know you've done counting (useful if your table is huge).

```
var rowid1 = 'parent_1';
var rowid2 = 'parent_2';

var rows = $("#"+rowid1).parent().find('tr');
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    var el = rows.get(i);

    // Done counting
    if (el.id == rowid2) break;

    if (el.id != rowid1) {
        ++count;
    }
}

alert("There are " + count + " rows between");
```

Comment: Still bad if the table's huge and parent_1 is towards the end of the table!

Answer (score 2):

Some people have some nice answers here, i was already started on mine so ill just add it for extra info.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    n = 0;
    var x = new Array(0,0,0);

    $("table tr").each(function(i)
    {
        if($(this).hasClass("child"))
        {
            x[n] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            n += 1;
        }
    });

    for(var y = 0; y < x.length; y++)
    {
        alert(x[y]);
    }
});
```

EDIT btw mine does not care how many parents are there, it will just keep counting as long the array is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming parent_1 and parent_2 are the start and the end rows respectively:

```
$("#parent_1").siblings().size() - 1
```

Comment: Why would it matter what order they're in?