# jQuery: count number of rows in a table

Tags: jquery, count, row

How do I count the number of tr elements within a table using jQuery?

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613024/count-number-of-table-rows-between-two-specific-rows-with-jquery), but I just want the total rows.

Answer (score 1058, accepted):

Use a selector that will select all the rows and take the length.

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
```

Note: this approach also counts all trs of every nested table!

Comment: $('#myTable tr').size() will return the same value.

Comment: @Garry -- the docs indicate that length is preferred over size() because it's faster.

Comment: .size() calls .length internally

Comment: I've always wondered what the point of the size method was. Did length not exist originally and it's just there for backward compatibility?

Comment: It has a length property because it's an array.  I don't know enough of the history of jQuery to know whether the jQuery object always extended an array.

Comment: After a little research, I can only find data supporting that the .size method was implemented specifically for textual elements (ie., input type="text", textarea, etc).

Comment: This will also count tr in the thead... $('#myTable tbody tr').length; will count those only in table bodies..

Comment: @TomRegan - I think that's only true if you are storing the result in a variable. In that case, yes you would need to redo the selection since the previous one was storing the results on the table before the addition - or are you taking the length of the result of `after` - that wouldn't do the same thing at all.

Comment: those who gets confused with `.size()` and `.length`, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/14202745/5289704

Comment: How can we calculate the number of rows for **a specific value** in a `td`? Say there are 10 rows and some of the rows have value **Manila** in the `city` column, how do we get all those rows with **Manila**?

Comment: How to do it when the table is submitted as variable (and not via an ID)?

Answer (score 205):

If you use `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` in your table, you'll have to use the following syntax or you'll get a incorrect value:

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
```

Comment: I'm using <tbody> but I get the same value

Comment: use $('#myTable >tbody:last >tr').length;

Comment: You must also remember that if you use this solution, you won't actually get a COUNT since, by definition, the 'length' attribute is zero-based.

Comment: @DevlshOne That is not true, length is not zero base, check the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: When you have nested tables, this will only count the rows in the specified table, which is what I needed.

Comment: Is there a difference between $('#myTable >tbody >tr') and $('#myTable  tbody tr') ?

Comment: @FrenkyB Technically yes. In terms of results it only matters if the table with id myTable has nested tables. > signifies 'direct child' is css.

Comment: @AntonChanning : How can we calculate the number of rows for **a specific value** in a `td`? Say there are 10 rows and some of the rows have value **Manila** in the `city` column, how do get all those rows with **Manila**?

Comment: @user12379095 Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101764/trouble-getting-count-of-table-rows-that-contain-certain-text

Answer (score 52):

Alternatively...

```
var rowCount = $('table#myTable tr:last').index() + 1;
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/6v67a/)

This will ensure that any nested table-rows are not also counted.

Comment: Oh, because then index returns -1.  Clever.

Comment: Thanks. They are few and far between but clever solutions do slip out now and again.

Comment: `var rowCount = $('table#myTable tr:last').index() + 1;`

Comment: Ignores `<thead>` rows and nested table rows. Nice. http://jsfiddle.net/6v67a/1576/

Comment: If Last `<td>` has inner table, it returns row count of that table!! http://jsfiddle.net/6v67a/1678/

Answer (score 35):

Well, I get the attr rows from the table and get the length for that collection:

```
$("#myTable").attr('rows').length;
```

I think that jQuery works less.

Comment: +1 - Good for the scenario where you are passed element that contains a table eg var rowCount = $(element).attr('rows').length;

Comment: Using JQuery v1.9.0 and I must use prop() to access 'rows': $("#myTable").prop('rows').length; (Chromium 24)

Answer (score 18):

Here's my take on it:

```
//Helper function that gets a count of all the rows <TR> in a table body <TBODY>
$.fn.rowCount = function() {
    return $('tr', $(this).find('tbody')).length;
};
```

**USAGE:**

```
var rowCount = $('#productTypesTable').rowCount();
```

Comment: Very nice function @Ricky G, useful to do several things example this function can be called for html generated from backend instead of dom as well.. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I got the following:

```
jQuery('#tableId').find('tr').index();
```

Comment: plus 1 to get the number of rows

Answer (score 12):

> try this one if there is tbody

Without Header

```
$("#myTable > tbody").children.length
```

If there is header then

```
$("#myTable > tbody").children.length -1
```

***Enjoy!!!***

Comment: It is missing () after chidlren =>  $("#myTable > tbody").children().length

Comment: The header should be enclosed in `<thead>` which should come before `<tbody>`. So the -1 should not be needed, if the table is properly designed according to the standard.

Comment: problem is , when datatable has no record it shows length as 1, because datatable render a empty row with class "odd" in datatable .....

Comment: I have a dynamic table on a UserScript and this was the only solution that worked

Answer (score 9):

I found this to work really well if you want to count rows without counting the th and any rows from tables inside of tables:

```
var rowCount = $("#tableData > tbody").children().length;
```

Comment: How to modify it to count columns?

Answer (score 7):

I needed a way to do this in an AJAX return, so I wrote this piece:

```
<p id="num_results">Number of results: <span></span></p>

<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    ajax();
})

//Function that makes Ajax call out to receive search results
var ajax = function() {
    //Setup Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/url', //URL to load
        type: 'GET', //Type of Ajax call
        dataType: 'html', //Type of data to be expected on return
        success: function(data) { //Function that manipulates the returned AJAX'ed data
            $('#results').html(data); //Load the data into a HTML holder
            var $el = $('#results'); //jQuery Object that is holding the results
            setTimeout(function(){ //Custom callback function to count the number of results
                callBack($el);
            });
        }
    });
}

//Custom Callback function to return the number of results
var callBack = function(el) {
    var length = $('tr', $(el)).not('tr:first').length; //Count all TR DOM elements, except the first row (which contains the header information)
    $('#num_results span').text(length); //Write the counted results to the DOM
}
</script>
```

Obviously this is a quick example, but it may be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

```
row_count =  $('#my_table').find('tr').length;
column_count =  $('#my_table').find('td').length / row_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var trLength = jQuery('#tablebodyID >tr').length;`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.