# How to count the entire number of rows in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using a datatable for my application. How do I get the total count of the rows in the datatable `onload`? My code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#jobSearchResultTable').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "scrollY": 500,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "aaSorting": []
  });
)};
```

How to get the total count of rows in the datatable `onload`

Comment: dataTable is not defined showing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update for New Versions**

```
table.data().count()
```

Reference:https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()

**For older versions:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Initialize your table
 var table = $('#jobSearchResultTable').dataTable();
 //Get the total rows
 alert(table.fnGetData().length);
});
```

Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238047/jquery-datatables-row-count-across-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238047/jquery-datatables-row-count-across-pages/)

Another method:

```
table.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
```

see which one works for you

Source: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2278/how-to-get-number-of-rows/

Comment: does not work for me, the table is dynamic populated.

Comment: I just tried. `table.fnGetData().length` is not working. `table.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();` works

Comment: table['context'][0]['aiDisplay'].length work for me even after search .Check my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58746208/5803974

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working for me. But i tried the following "$('#TableId').DataTable().rows().count();". Hope this helps

Answer (score 30):

If you're using the new DataTables (v1.10+), you don't have access to some legacied functions such as fnGetData().

Instead, try this:

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
var table_length = table.data().count();
```

If you're using paging (which I was), and need the total count across all pages, try this:

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    'paging': true
});

var length = table.page.info().recordsTotal;
```

Sources:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()

https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

Comment: table.page.info().recordsTotal; this works perfectly

Comment: table.data().count() gives the total number of cells (tds) in data table. table.data().rows().count() gives you the count of rows.

Comment: perfect answer for paging, Thanks!!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer! I'm using server-side paging and don't have access to all of the rows. This does the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Get response from serverside processing following way it works for me:

```
// tested with : DataTables 1.10.15
t1 = $('#item-list').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":'url',
    "drawCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {  
        console.log(this.fnSettings().json); /* for json response you can use it also*/ 
        alert(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()); // total number of rows
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: None of the solution worked for me except this one. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#jobSearchResultTable').dataTable().rows().count()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Praveen Please check after filter (search) in table

Comment: This has at least 2 problems: (1) you have to use `.DataTable()` not `.dataTable()` in order to use `.rows()`, and (2) it returns the FILTERED number of rows, not the total number.

Answer (score 2):

I tried most of the solution from the answers but not worked for me.

Some work but when we search,it shows same number instead number of rows after search.

```
 var tbl=$('#tbl_name').DataTable();
 console.log(tbl['context'][0]['aiDisplay'].length);
```

Its worked for me even after search,shows current number of rows after search.

Answer (score 2):

**October 2021** for Yajra Datatables

```
myTable.rows().count();
```

Comment: example :        
 var table = $('#LGAllLegalCase').DataTable();
 var oV = table.rows().count();

Answer (score 1):

According to your description I assume that you have table with id="jobSearchResultTable".

Try this it could work for you.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#jobSearchResultTable').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "scrollY":  500,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "jQueryUI":       true,
    "aaSorting": []

   });
   var count=0;
   $('#jobSearchResultTable tr').each(function(){
      count++;
   });
   alert(count);
```

)};

This will show the no of rows in the table.

Comment: but i want the total row count i.e it is showing the current page row count i.e if the table has 50 rows then i want  the count as 50 ,not as 10 perpage

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238047/jquery-datatables-row-count-across-pages?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following code

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
alert(
    'Number of row entries: '+
    table
        .column( 0 )
        .data()
        .length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

//get number of entire rows

table.rows().eq(0).length;

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I know that you do not have the comment privilege, but you can get enough reputation in a single day...

Answer (score 0):

I just read the table instance in console and got this in version 1.10.8

```
var table = $("#mytable").DataTable({})
var total = table.settings()[0].json.recordsTotal
```

Hope this helps