# jQuery - Ability to count the number of Rows in a Table?

Tags: jquery

w jQuery - is it possible to setup a listener that can count the number of rows in a table.

And when the row count changes do X if the count is eq 0 or Y is > 0?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table

Comment: @Martin thx but that has nothing to do with observing the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use time listener :

```
 var time = setInterval(function(){   
                                   alert( $('#table tr').length ); 
                                  },1000 );
```

Or you can put it when the event associated with change num rows executed .

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
$('table tr').length;
```

Comment: `$('#some-table tr').length;` would seem to be more appropriate, in case the page has more than one table on it.

Answer (score 0):

Both [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) and [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) will give you the same information.  If the table ID is `tbl1`, then you use the jQuery CSS selector

```
$('#tbl1 tr')
```

If you are using `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` properly, then you should use the below to count only the body rows, otherwise take 1 or 2 off the `.length` result from the above.

```
$('#tbl1 tbody tr')
```

As for observing the row count changes, you need either

1. a global var that stores the current row count, coupled with a setInterval event (say 100ms) that checks for changes and raises an event; or
2. a class that encapsulates this behaviour with an internal var, but also using setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$('#tableID').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    var count = $('table tr').length;
    alert("The number of rows has changed, there are now " + count + " rows.");
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gdSPj/).