# How to count <tr> elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex, rowcount

I'm new with jquery and I want to count the existing  elements from a table and the html structure is like:

```
<table summary="">
    <tr>
       <td>
           <table id="myid" some more attributes> <-- i got that id and 
               <tbody>
                   <tr>foo</tr> <---counting
                   <tr>bar</tr> <---counting
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
HTML is apex gernerated.
```

i've tried jquery statements from [jQuery: count number of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table) an many more sits but nothing worked for me.
My not working "solution" is

```
 $("table[id='myid'] > tbody >tr").length
```

or

```
 $('table#myid >tbody:last >tr').length
```

I'm thankful for any hints and tips

Mario

Comment: Including nested tables?

Comment: the `id` in your HTML is `myid`, but your jQuery selector is looking for `table_id`. Is this a typo on your part?

Comment: oh my bad. copy & past from my js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is what you should use, just with the right id:

```
$("table[id='myid'] > tbody > tr").length
```

or

```
$("table#myid > tbody > tr").length
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bbV3Z/

As the id should be unique in the page, you should be able to use just:

```
$("#myid > tbody > tr").length
```

The reason for using `#myid > tbody > tr` instead of just `#myid tr` is to make sure that you only get the rows in that specific table, and not rows from tables nested inside it. If you don't have any tables nested inside it, you can just use:

```
$("#myid tr").length
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('table#myid tr').length​`.

#### References:

- [ID Selector ("#id")](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [Descendant Selector ("ancestor descendant")](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: However, that would also include rows from tables nested inside it, if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7Nea/1/

JS

```
$('#myid tbody tr').length);
```

Comment: However, that would also include rows from tables nested inside it, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean inside your specific table

```
$('#myid tr').length // <-- this gets all tr inside table with id=myid
```

Or if you really wanted to traverse the dom and be more specific in case theres another table inside that table

```
$('#myid > tbody > tr').length
```

Plus you're already using the `ID` selector so no need to have `table#myid`

Comment: That will count the row in the outer table also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#table_id tr").length`

Comment: However, that would also include rows from tables nested inside it, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var count = $('#myid tr').length;`.

Comment: However, that would also include rows from tables nested inside it, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Think about performances also by takeing the context first :

`$('#myid').find('tr')`

here's the perfs comparisons : http://jsperf.com/tr-number

Comment: I've also added all other answer snippets on this thread for comparison, feel free to look at it...