# Object.getOwnPropertyNames vs Object.keys

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.keys` in javascript?  Also some examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Judging from MDN articles on both, the difference is, whether the returned list includes the non-enumerable properties: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) does not return them, while [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) does.

Comment: [MDN: Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Answer (score 393, accepted):

There is a little difference. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)` returns *all* own properties of the object `a`. `Object.keys(a)` returns all *enumerable* own properties. It means that if you define your object properties without making some of them `enumerable: false` these two methods will give you the same result.

It's easy to test:

```
var a = {};
Object.defineProperties(a, {
    one: {enumerable: true, value: 1},
    two: {enumerable: false, value: 2},
});
Object.keys(a); // ["one"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a); // ["one", "two"]
```

If you define a property without providing property attributes descriptor (meaning you don't use `Object.defineProperties`), for example:

```
a.test = 21;
```

then such a property becomes enumerable automatically and will appear in both methods’ returned arrays.

Comment: In particular, the `length` properties of array objects is not enumerable, so it doesn't show up in `Object.keys`.

Comment: @Barmar The `length` property of objects is on the prototype, not the object itself, so neither `Object.keys` nor `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will list it.

Comment: @TheQodesmith the result of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(anyArray)` includes `length`

Comment: I stand corrected! `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(anyArray)` indeed does include `length` in the returned array!

Comment: Yeah, but Array.prototype has it, too.
It's kind of weird that one can modify Array.prototype like a normal array (i.e. Array.prototype.push('whatever')). But it seems to have no effect on newly created Array instances.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020958/why-is-length-a-property-of-array-not-array-prototype-chain

Comment: DIY `length` property is not enumerable: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor([], 'length')`

Comment: array is an Array Instance, It's nature to have its own 'length' property. Which does not mean that an ordinary object should always have an 'length' property.

Answer (score 37):

Another difference is in case of array `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` method will return an extra property  that is `length`.

```
var x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
Object.keys(x);  //[ '0', '1', '2', '3' ]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x);  //[ '0', '1', '2', '3', 'length' ]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Literal notation vs constructor when creating object.** Here is something that got me.

```
const cat1 = {
    eat() {},
    sleep() {},
    talk() {}
};

// here the methods will be part of the Cat Prototype
class Cat {
    eat() {}
    sleep() {}
    talk() {}
}

const cat2 = new Cat()

Object.keys(cat1) // ["eat", "sleep", "talk"]
Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(cat2)) // []

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cat1) // ["eat", "sleep", "talk"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(cat2)) // ["eat", "sleep", "talk"]

cat1 // {eat: function, sleep: function, talk: function}
cat2 // Cat {}

// a partial of a function that is used to do some magic redeclaration of props
function foo(Obj) {
    var propNames = Object.keys(Obj);

    // I was missing this if
    // if (propNames.length === 0) {
    //     propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Obj);
    // }

    for (var prop in propNames) {
        var propName = propNames[prop];

        APIObject[propName] = "reasign/redefine or sth";
    }
}
```

So in my case the `foo` function didn't work if I gave it objects of the cat2 type.

There are other ways to create objects so there could be other kinks in there as well.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will return the property names for `cat1` and not `cat2`. The two ways of creating the object do not produce a difference between `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.keys`.

Comment: @Boric Yes you are correct. I could have meant to use Object.getPrototypeOf(cat2) with both methods instead of just cat2. I can't be for sure because I don't remember and don't have the code. I will fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As was already explained, `.keys` doesn't return non-enumerable properties.

Regarding to examples, one of pitfall cases is an `Error` object: some of its properties are non-enumerable.
So while `console.log(Object.keys(new Error('some msg')))` yields `[]`,
`console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Error('some msg')))` yields `["stack", "message"]`

```js
console.log(Object.keys(new Error('some msg')));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Error('some msg')));
```

Answer (score -6):

Another difference is that (at least with nodejs) "getOwnPropertyNames" function does not guarantee keys order, that's why I usually use "keys" function :

```
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
      if (!o.propertyIsEnumerable(k)) return;
      // do something...
    });
```

Comment: Is that still the case in current versions of Node.js, and if so, do you know any examples of `getOwnPropertyNames` not being in order? Because ES2015 specifies [an order for `Obect.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames), while the [order for `Obect.keys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys) is still up to the implementation.

Comment: I always thought there was no order of JS object keys and you shouldn't rely on it even if an implementation keeps the order?

Comment: Um, I think it's the other way round; the order for getOwnPropertyNames is defined in the spec. Object.keys is up to the implementation.

Comment: All of the following have unspecified order: `for-in loop`, `Object.keys`, and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. That said, all three will enumerate in a consistent order with respect to one another.