# Why doesn't Object.keys(window) or for(k in window) return Math?

Tags: javascript

I am building a javascript editor autocomplete, and I would like to list all top-level things that are available. I tried:

```
Object.keys(window)
```

and

```
for (k in window)
```

but it doesn't look like either is returning things like 'Math' or 'Array'. How can I get *everything* from window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object.getOwnPropertyNames() contains Math, Array, ... etc.

check this question : [Object.getOwnPropertyNames vs Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys)