# JavaScript Object.keys returning empty array

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to get the keys from a JavaScript Object.  When I inspect the object I can see that there is a key value pair on the object but when I run `Object.keys(myObject)` I get an empty array returned.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I'm following this documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

And the function which creates the object is as follows:

```
query: function () {
  var query = {}
  _.each(this.$el.find('input:checked'), function (el, index) {
    Object.defineProperty(query, el.id, {value: el.value})
  })
  return query
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys` only returns _enumerable_ _own_ keys. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Comment: OMG thanks. you saved me a whole lot of pain & head scratching

Comment: I can't find a duplicate - so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Object.keys` only returns *enumerable* *own* keys. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Answer (score 6):

`Console.log` prints the most recent value of its contents and *not* the value of that content at that specific time of execution.

To log the array, try deep-cloning its value to another variable and then console log it.

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(keys)));
```

Comment: This answer deserves way more credit. Thank you so much!