# why inherited (have confusion if it is inherited at all) properties are being enumerated in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, enumeration

I knew that inherited properties are not enumerable. In the following code `stanford` inherits a property `level` from another object `university`.

But when I enumerate `stanford`, I see that the inherited property also being listed. Please explain the matter (i must be wrong somewhere).

```
var university = {level:"bachelor"};

var stanford = Object.create(university);
stanford.country = "USA";
stanford.rating = "Good";

console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty("level"));    //  false

for(var properties in stanford){                //  level, country, rating
    console.log(properties);
}
```

Comment: Because `for..in` iterates over all properties in the prototype chain. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a wonderful [link!!](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch17.html) Thanks @Sajib Biswas for this question.

Refer [object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys)

and [how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

I think This may help :

```
var proto = Object.defineProperties({}, {
  protoEnumTrue: { value: 1, enumerable: true },
  protoEnumFalse: { value: 2, enumerable: false }
});
var obj = Object.create(proto, {
  objEnumTrue: { value: 1, enumerable: true },
  objEnumFalse: { value: 2, enumerable: false }
});

for (var x in obj) console.log(x);

Results: 

objEnumTrue
protoEnumTrue


console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ["objEnumTrue"]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)); //  ["objEnumTrue", "objEnumFalse"]
```

The enumeration will return properties not just of the object being enumerated, but also from the prototypes of any parent objects.

**Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)** returns all own properties of the object a.
**Object.keys(a)** returns all enumerable own properties.

From Your Example:

```
var university = {level:"bachelor"};

var stanford = Object.create(university);
stanford.country = "USA";
stanford.rating = "Good";

console.log(university.hasOwnProperty("level"));    //  true
console.log(university.hasOwnProperty("country"));    //  false

console.log(stanford.hasOwnProperty("country"));    //  true
console.log(stanford.hasOwnProperty("level"));    //  false
```

Answer (score 1):

> which properties are not enumerable?

Javascript has two types of object properties: `Data` properties and `Accessor` properties. In your case you are working with `data` properties.
To manipulate `enumeration` of certain property use property descriptor with `Object.defineProperty()` method.
Example:

```
 var stanford = Object.create(university);
    stanford.country = "USA";
    stanford.rating = "Good";
    Object.defineProperty(stanford, 'rating', {
        enumerable: false
    });

 console.log(Object.keys(stanford)); // Now you won't see 'rating' here
 // the same effect takes place for loop operators (for;;) , for .. in ..)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure of your `stanford`-object:

[image]

As you can see it inherits the other Object wich has the property `level`, but does not "hasOwnProperty" `level`. However `for..in` will loop over all properties.