# How to map a dictionary in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a dictionary from an online api in the form of {{key: object}, {key: object},... For like 1000 Objects}. I would like to use reactJS to do something like

```
this.props.dict.map(function(object, key)){
 //Do stuff
}
```

This map works with arrays but it obviously doesn't work with dictionaries. How can I achieve something similar?

Comment: Is that an object of objects? Or an array of objects? Or an object with a bunch of keys which point to objects?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Dictionaries" in Javascript are called objects and you can iterate over them in a very similar way to arrays.

```
var dict = this.props.dict;

for (var key in dict) {
  // Do stuff. ex: console.log(dict[key])
}
```

If you were thinking of using map so that at the end of the iteration you had a complete array, then inside your `for..in` loop you could push to an array you declare earlier.

```
var dict = this.props.dict;
var arr = [];

for (var key in dict) {
  arr.push(dict[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 39):

If you target modern browsers or use some kind of transpiler you may use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to map `[key, value]` pairs within single iteration.

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 42
}

console.log('Object.entries')
console.log(
  Object.entries(obj)
)

console.log('Mapping')
console.log(
  Object.entries(obj)
  .map( ([key, value]) => `My key is ${key} and my value is ${value}` )
)
```

---

### Usage with React

`Object.entries` function is very handy with React as by default there is no easy iteration of objects/dictionaries. React requires you to assign keys to components when iterating in order to perform it's diffing algorithm. By using `Object.entries` you can leverage already keyed collections without manually injecting keys in your data or using array indices, which can lead to undesired behavior when indices change after filtering, removing or adding items.

Please see following example of `Object.entries` usage with React:

```js
const buttonCaptions = {
  close: "Close",
  submit: "Submit result",
  print: "print",
}

const Example = () =>
  <div>
  {
    Object.entries(buttonCaptions)
    .map( ([key, value]) => <button key={key}>{value}</button> )
  }
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Common syntax errors

As a side note, please keep in mind that when mapping result of the `Object.entries` you must wrap the array argument in parentheses when using array destructuring. Following code will throw syntax error:

```js
console.log(
  Object.entries({key: 'value'})
  .map([key, value] => `${key}: ${value}`)
)
```

Do this instead:

```js
console.log(
  Object.entries({key: 'value'})
  .map( ([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}` )
)
    
console.log(
  Object.entries({key: 'value'})
  .map(keyValuePair => `${keyValuePair[0]}: ${keyValuePair[1]}`)
)
```

---

### Compatibility

For the current browser support please see the [ECMAScript compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus) under 2017 features > Object static methods.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `map` as you usually would one option is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`:

```
var newArr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.props.dict).map(function(key) {
    var currentObj = this.props.dict[key];
    // do stuff...
    return val;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant: `{key: object, key2: object}`

You could do something like(not sure the exact differences to `getOwnPropertyNames` but it should do about same maybe less performant):

```
Object.keys(this.props.dict)
    .map(function(key)){ 
         var object = this.props.dict[key]
         //Do stuff
     })
```

Edit:

- [Object.getOwnPropertyNames vs Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys)

If you only want the enumerables of the object use `Object.keys`