# Function not listed under Object.keys or Object.getOwnPropertyNames but can be invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Suppose there is some library javascript object `jsObj`. On calling `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` , I get a list of properties like

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

But still I can call a function like `jsObj.e()`. Why the the method `e` is not part of `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`? How they are doing it?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys), it says that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will return non enumerable properties too. So what is the characterstic of property like `e` above.

I am using [opentok](https://www.tokbox.com/developer/sdks/node/) server side SDK. Using following code,

```
var OpenTok = require('opentok');
var opentok = new OpenTok(config.tokbox.apiKey, config.tokbox.secret);
console.log("opentok1", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(opentok));
prints -> // [ '_client',
  'apiKey',
  'apiSecret',
  'apiUrl',
  'startArchive',
  'stopArchive',
  'getArchive',
  'deleteArchive',
  'listArchives' ] 
console.log("opentok2", opentok.createSession);
prints -> function (...){...}
```

Comment: Do share executable demo.. Unable to understand the issue....

Comment: It's probably inherited from one of its prototypes? 
If you do this: `for(prop in obj) { console.log(prop); }`
(where obj is your object), does it get outputted then?

Comment: Added some code, not executable because you need your own api keys. Hopefully, that will explain the question clearly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.e` must be defined on the object's prototype. Like this:

```
var test = function() {}
test.prototype = { e: function() { return 'e'; } }
var obj = new test();
Object.keys(obj) // returns []
obj.e() // returns 'e'
```

A way of getting the prototypes keys is simply getting the prototype and the use the `Object.keys()` function:

```
Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
```

This will however not give you keys of the prototypes prototype.

Comment: Is there a way to list all property of the object's prototype.

Comment: Use "for in" as this will list all properties of the object and those inherited by its prototype.

Comment: Updated my answer. You could also use the `for ... in` as @evolutionxbox says, but if it's a list you want, then you have to build it yourself with the `for ... in` method.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list for good solution on using `for ... in`

Answer (score 3):

The propety of an JS Object could be

- own -- means it is defined on the object directly
- inherited -- the property is callable, but is defined in prototype (the Object predecessor)
- enumerable / not enumerable -- some properties (like `length`) are not enumerable, you can define your own non enumerable property with [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

then iterating functions works on some subset of this properties:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) -- returns *an array of a given object's own enumerable properties*.
- [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) -- returns *an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object*

so none of this function iterates over inherited properties. If you wanna iterate all properties without resolution of ownership, then you need [`for... in cycle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), like:

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in object)
    keys.push(key);
```

but this will not iterate over non-enumerable properties.

For complete overview of ownership and enumerability [see this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).