# ngFor from object?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 / Angular, but I realized that the ngFor function can't read objects. Also, I need it to be shown only if the `cart` is not empty.

Object:

```
{
    "48131": {
        "code":"D40905",
        "name":"ДАМСКА ПЛЕТЕНА БЛУЗА КЪС РЪКАВ ЩАМПА REASON",
        "price":"18.99",
        "size":"STANDART",
        "qty":"1"
    },
    "49410": {
        "code":"D41821",
        "name":"ДАМСКА БЛУЗА ТРИКО",
        "price":"44.99",
        "size":"M",
        "qty":"4"
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let p of cart">
    <ion-col col-3>
        <div><img src="http://example.com/products/small/{{p.code}}-1.jpg" /></div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-9>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <div>{{p.name}}</div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <div>{{p.qty}} бр ({{p.size}} размер) x <b>{{p.price}} лв</b></div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <div (click)="deleteCart({{p.id}})">Изтрий <ion-icon name='trash' item-start color="danger"></ion-icon></div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Can someone help me with this? I've tried so many things...

Comment: can you show what the cart object looks like? doesn't seem to be an array.

Comment: Yes duplicate import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value): any {
    if(!value) return null;
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
<div *ngFor="let key of member | keys">{{member[key]}}</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Pipe for that purpose

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'object' 
})
export class ObjectForPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, arg1): any {
        return typeof value!=='object' ? [] : Object.keys(value);
    }
}
```

In AppModule -> `@NgModule`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ObjectForPipe } from 'path-to-pipe/object.pipe.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ObjectForPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let key of objs | object">
```

From version 6.1, Angular introduced keyValue Pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
   {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried with the `@Pipe`, but I always get errors. This time - `@Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`. When I add it in ngModule, I receive the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer with all you need to do it works.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Which is weird, since I see that the object is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your card json is not array. It should be

```
[
    "48131": {
        "code":"D40905",
        "name":"ДАМСКА ПЛЕТЕНА БЛУЗА КЪС РЪКАВ ЩАМПА REASON",
        "price":"18.99",
        "size":"STANDART",
        "qty":"1"
    },
    "49410": {
        "code":"D41821",
        "name":"ДАМСКА БЛУЗА ТРИКО",
        "price":"44.99",
        "size":"M",
        "qty":"4"
    }
]
```

Comment: key, value pairs are not valid in arrays.

Comment: nice bong!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Convert your json object to an array based on this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37667589/2013245

Then you should be fine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16630149)

Comment: well said. corrected.