# No functions in Object.keys(document)

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I add a `function` to an `object` it is being part of `Object.keys(myObj)` while this is not the case for e.g. `document.getElementById` and `Object.keys(document)`

```js
var myObj = {}
myObj.text = "hi"
myObj.func = function(){}

console.log(Object.keys(myObj))
console.log(Object.keys(document))

console.log(typeof myObj)
console.log(typeof document)
console.log(typeof myObj.func)
console.log(typeof document.getElementById)
```

Note that while

1. `for(var foo in document)` gives me `getElementById` (among many others),
2. `for(var foo in Object.getPrototypeOf(document))` also seems to give me the same values and
3. `Object.getPrototypeOf(document)` returns `HTMLDocument`

`for(var foo in HTMLDocument)` just gives me what seems to be `Object.keys(Node)` (`Object.getPrototypeOf(HTMLDocument)` is `Node`):

```js
var resArr = []
for(var foo in document) resArr.push(foo)
console.log("results (var foo in document): " + resArr.length)
var resArr = []
for(var foo in Object.getPrototypeOf(document)) resArr.push(foo)
console.log("results (var foo in Object.getPrototypeOf(document)): " + resArr.length)
var resArr = []
for(var foo in HTMLDocument) resArr.push(foo)
console.log("results (var foo in HTMLDocument): " + resArr.length)
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(document): " + Object.getPrototypeOf(document))
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === HTMLDocument: " + (Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === HTMLDocument))
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(document) == HTMLDocument: " + (Object.getPrototypeOf(document) == HTMLDocument))
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(document) instanceof HTMLDocument: " + (Object.getPrototypeOf(document) instanceof HTMLDocument))
```

Also note that contrary to what [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) suggests by marking this as duplicate of [22658488](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys) `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(document)` doesn't return those additional members (as `getElementById`) either:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(document))
```

Comment: Because `getElementById` is not directly defined on `document` object but on one of its prototype chain i.e. `Document` .

Comment: Thanks! Still I don't have `getElementById` in `Object.keys(HTMLDocument.prototype)` (only `["fgColor", "linkColor", "vlinkColor", "alinkColor", "bgColor", "all", "clear", "captureEvents", "releaseEvents"]`)

Comment: See the edited comment, it is defined on `Document ` object. Also use `Object.getPrototypeOf(HTMLDocument)` to get the prototype of Object. There is difference between the two.

Comment: Ok, what I wanted is probably the list of 244 entries the [for…in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) gives me. Is there a functional equivalent? Apparently neither `Object.keys()` nor `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` are, right?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `Object.keys` equivalent function which enumerates the object's prototype properties. You'll have to use `for...in` loop.

Comment: The `for…in` loops of `Document`, `HTMLDocument` and `Node` all seem to give me what is defined in `Node` (`Object.keys(Node)`) (and doesn't include `getElementById` and the many other properties `for (var foo in document)` gives me).
Also `Object.getPrototypeOf` tells me that `Node` is the `prototype` of both `Document` and `HTMLDocument`, while the `prototype` of `document` is shown to be `HTMLDocument` (not `Document`).
Still i don't know where all the rest comes from

Comment: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) might be the closest to `for…in` allthough it doesn't iterate through the prototype chain