# Find Array length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This will sound a very silly question. How can we find the exact length of array in JavaScript; more precisely i want to find the total positions occupied in the array.

I have a simple scenario which i guess most of you might be aware of.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.length; //This will output 3
```

Now if i give

```
a[100] = 100;
a.length; // The output is 101;
```

I want to get the exact size of the array which in the above case should be 4.

Comment: check for the first undefined value if the array is filled in incremental order.

Comment: do a for loop and increment counter other than `undefined`

Comment: In Javascript arrays are not created with bounded length, so when you do a[0] = 1; a[100] = 100, length becomes `101`. One thing you can do is loop from 0 -> array.length and keep track of values which are not `undefined`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar do you mean something like this for (i= 0 ; a[i] != undefined || a[i] != null ;i++); but this wont work in our case. As it will stop the loop at index = 3;

Comment: @Yameen http://jsfiddle.net/kwu3xqsm/

Comment: Why are you creating an array with holes if you don't seem to want an array with holes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are looking for is not the length of an array but the number values allocated in that array.

`Array.length` will NOT give you that result but the total number of values allocated.

A workarround is to count the properties of the object behind the array, with:

```
Object.keys(a).length
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties

But with some caveats:

- It will also count literal properties, like a.a_property. I do not think that is what you want.
  So, you will have to filter that result:

`!(+el % 1)` which check if `el` can be considered as numerical property even if it has a type of string.

- you want count only positive integers, so you have to filter them with:

`+el>=0`

- finally, as array size is limited to 2^32, you will to also filter positive integers greater than that:

`+el < Math.pow(2,32)`

Functionally, you will have your result with this filter:

```
Array.realLength= Object.keys(a).filter(function(el){return !(+el % 1) && +el>=0 && +el < Math.pow(2,32) ;}).length
```

Comment: This should work most of the time, but will be incorrect if someone has assigned non-numeric properties to the array.

Comment: This will returns all the keys, numeric or not.

Comment: Technically every property with number value `> 2^32 - 2` is not considered to be an array element either, but that is very theoretical at that point ;)

Comment: and float values too :-)

Comment: @Gael So far this is the best quick solution that answers my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Yameen The first sample in this answer can produce wrong results. And the second example (the more reliable one) is far more convoluted than the one at the end of my post (`a.filter(function () { return true; }).length`).

Comment: Did you never think, how ridiculous this is?

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR The simplest reliable approach that I can think of is the following:

```
var count = a.filter(function() { return true; }).length;
```

In modern JavaScript engines, this could be shortened to:

```
var count = a.filter(() => true).length;
```

---

Full answer:

Checking against `undefined` isn't enough because the array could actually *contain* `undefined` values.

Reliable ways to find the number of elements are...

Use the `in` operator:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    if (i in a) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

use `.forEach()` (which basically uses `in` under the hood):

```js
var a = [1, undefined, null, 7];
a[50] = undefined;
a[90] = 10;

var count = 0;
a.forEach(function () {
    count += 1;
});

console.log(count);    // 6
```

or use `.filter()` with a predicate that is always true:

```js
var a = [1, undefined, null, 7];
a[50] = undefined;
a[90] = 10;

var count = a.filter(function () { return true; }).length;

console.log(count);    // 6
```

Comment: That's why we don't check for `undefined`. We check if it's NOT undefined and increment some counter in that case and repeat this from 0 -> array length :)

Comment: @Arkantos Checking that each element is not `undefined` can yield a count that is lower than the actual number of elements, and that is exactly my point.

Comment: Oops my mistake.. I was talking in the context of the OP's array where he has only integers in his array :)

Answer (score 0):

the size of the array is exactly what is shown by the length property.

even though you gave a value only to the first 3 positions(0,1,2), when you gave the value 100 to the a[100], you resized it to 101 positions. Therefore, you'll get the count of every position, from 0(first index) to 100(last index), even if they have no value.

Answer (score 0):

With your code: `a[100] = 100`, you are creating a block at location 100 in your array. (Total of 101 since it starts at 0).

If you want to see how many actual answers are in the block you would have to use a loop and cycle through checking which fields are not equal to undefined. There are dozens of ways to do this with `for`, `while`, `foreach`, etc.

Just implement a counter and count the sections in the array that are not equal to `null` or `undefined`. That will give you the number of places that are actually being used in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Determining the length of an array is a fundamental operation in JavaScript. We will explore multiple approaches to [find the length of an array](https://www.webdevlearners.com/find-the-length-of-an-array-in-javascript/). Please refer WebDevLearners for more details.

**Approach 1. Using length Property**
The most straightforward and commonly used method to find the length of an array is by accessing its length property. This property returns the number of elements in the array.

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arrayLength = myArray.length;

// Output: 5
console.log("The length of the array is:", arrayLength);
```

**Approach 2. Iterating with for Loop**
You can iterate through the array using a loop and count the elements to find the length.

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    count++;
}

// Output: 5
console.log("The length of the array is:", count);
```

Please refer [WebDevLearners](https://webdevlearners.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
a.filter(Boolean).length
```