# Ionic V4 JS Object

Tags: javascript, object, ionic-framework, ionic4

Working away on a Ionic-PouchDB - I'm new to both - and pretty basic at JS.

I have a service that returns data from PouchDB and an ngfor loop that populates the view.  It works fine

From the page typescript

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.slates = this.api.getSlates();
    }
```

From the HTML

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let slate of slates" (click)="openDetails(slate)">
  {{ slate.createdon | date:'EEE  - d - LLL hh:mm a yyyy' }} --- {{ slate._id }}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

If I console.log this.slates I get 
[image]
So far so good

I need to find out how many objects there are in the what look like an array - in this case 10.  Also need to be able to get hold of data in each element.
e.g. the _id or type from the objects

[image]

If I do say

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.slates = this.api.getSlates();
    console.log(this.slates);
    console.log(Object.keys(this.slates));
}
```

I just get an empty array.

Any help much appreciated - it'll help my sanity.

Comment: Duplicate for the first part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811911/find-array-length-in-javascript Traversing JSON seems like another question (which also likely has a duplicate). This isn't an Ionic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you can use

```
const numberOfSlates = this.slates.length;
```

For the second one you can use find() to get the first result:

```
const targetId = "slate:1546427619624:cameraa:x:5";
const foundItem = this.slates.find((slate) => slate["_id"] === targetId);
```

### Update - why is length = 0?

Based on your comments your seeing a zero length when checking right after.

You are correct, this is because the operation is async so its not populated straight away.

Without seeing the code for your `.getSlates()` this is just a guess but if it returns a promise then you can do:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getSlates().then((res) => {
       this.slates = res;
       console.log(this.slates);
       console.log(this.slates.length);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks rtpHarry     `const numberOfSlates = this.slates.length; `  used as ` console.log("Number of slates -- " + numberOfSlates);` gave me `Number of slates -- 0`  Is it because the call to PouchDB at the beginning is returning a promise which I am pushing onto an array before returning it to the `this.slates = this.api.getSlates();`    ?  and this is all being run within ngOnInit ?

Answer (score 2):

To get the length of the array, use

```
this.slates.length
```

Object.keys(this.slates) returns the keys from the key-value pairs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys