# NodeJS Count how many objects in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I count how many objects there are inside an array?

The array looking like:

```
[ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]
```

I assume I could use count() if it was PHP, but what about NodeJS/Javascript?

Edit:

[image: asd]

```
if (offer.items_to_receive.length > 0) { 
    console.log("items: " + offer.items_to_receive.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < offer.items_to_receive.length; i++) {
        usersInRound.push(offer.steamid_other);
    }
}

logData('Accepted trade offer from ' + offer.steamid_other + '. (tradeofferid: ' + offer.tradeofferid + ')\nWorth ' + offer.items_to_receive.length + ' tickets. ');
```

How come it can read the "worth X tickets", but not the other part?

Comment: if your question was caused by your own typo (something you seem to indicate in a comment), then please delete your question.

Comment: Well it seems it wasn't, two seconds, updating the post.

Comment: Based on your edit, `offer.items_to_receive` is `undefined`.  There is some problem earlier in your code that is making that property not be what you think it is.  And, you certainly can't read the `.length` property of `undefined`.  This should be basic debugging of your own code.

Comment: Well how come it can read it at the end? (Check the \nWorth X tickets part) it can read the .length there?

Comment: It can also read the .length of it at the "items" part.

Comment: Based on your screen shot, it's throwing an exception before it gets to your `for` loop.  This question is pretty screwed up.  First, you've completely changed it.  Second, you're not disclosing enough of the relevant code for anyone to have any idea what's going on.  Third, now you're claiming lines of code after the exception are working fine which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1
}, {
    id: 2
}];

console.log(data.length);
```

**Update**, in your edit I see that

`offer.items_to_receive` is `undefined`, ensure that object `offer` has property `items_to_receive` (should be array);

Answer (score 10):

```
list = //YOUR OBJECT DATA
```

`count= Object.keys(list).length;`

```
Object.keys() gives the count of keys
```

That should give proper count

Answer (score 1):

I think your question should be [How to get Array Size in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202601/array-size-vs-array-length)

***Answer:*** Use the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) method.

---

Examples:

```
[1,2,3].length
// => 3

var a = { num: 1, obj: {}, arr: [{}, 3, "asd", {q: 3}, 1] }
a.arr.length
// => 5
```