# How can I display count of mapped looped items in React

Tags: javascript, arrays

Notice in the code sample below that I'm mapping all the data into ResultItems

```
    {store.results.data.map( result =>
                                <ResultItem key={result.id}
                                title={result.title}
                                description={result.description}
                                start_date={result.start_date}
                                end_date={result.end_date}
                                vendor_name={result.vendor.name}
                                buyer_name={result.buyer.name}
                                preview_file={result.preview_file}
                                status={result.status}
                                />)}
```

what I want to do is keep count of how many resultitems there are and display that number in the DOM

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Uh... `store.results.data.length`?

Comment: that worked! thanks so much!

Comment: such a simple solution! it's late over here, I'm not thinking...too bad I can't vote this as best answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Count how many objects in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092193/nodejs-count-how-many-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use the length of the array to know how many items the array has or if you want to access each one just use the index of the map function.

```
    const length = store.results.data.length

    {store.results.data.map( (result, index) =>
           <ResultItem
               position={index}
               (...)
           />
    )}
```