# Everytime I run the discord bot, it says that the number of online members is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

This is the code

```
 module.exports = async (client) => {
        let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(guild.id)

            setInterval(() =>{

            var onlineCount = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status != "offline").size
    
            let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get(channel.id);
            console.log(onlineCount.name);
            memberCountChannel.setName(onlineCount + 'people online')
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch (error => console.log(error));
        }, 5000)
    }
```

And this is the part that counts the members

```
var onlineCount = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status != "offline").size
```

What the terminal shows

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are restarting the bot the data is not cached, you firstly need to fetch the members with [`<Guild>.members.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method.
Else it means you didn't activate intents, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/14346900).

Example for your case:

```
await myGuild.members.fetch();
var onlineCount = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status != "offline").size;
```

Comment: Could u please give me an example of how to do it? I haven't used this method before

Comment: await myGuild.members.fetch();

Comment: Before accessing the cache.

Comment: Don't I need an async function to use await?

Comment: Yes don't forget to put your `setInterval` function in `async` too.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` method returns an array, and arrays do not have `size` property. Use  `length` property and it will be ok.

Please check this answer also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14202745/10500500

```
var onlineCount = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status != "offline").length
```

Comment: `<Guild>.members.cache` is a Collection instance (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) and not an array.

Comment: Doesn't work still says undefined