# Discord JS V13 member.presence.status (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status'))

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const { GuildMember, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "guildMemberAdd",
    /**
     * @param {GuildMember} member
     */
    execute(member){
        const totalUsers = member.guild.channels.cache.get(process.env.totalUsers)
        const onlineUsers = member.guild.channels.cache.get(process.env.onlineUsers)

        var userCount = member.guild.memberCount
        var onlineCount = member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size

        totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
          
        onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)  

        member.guild.channels.cache.get(process.env.WELCOME_MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID).send({ 
            embeds: [
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Welcome! :smiley:")
                .setDescription(`${member.toString()} has joined the server!\n
                                Thanks for joining. Head over to <#${process.env.RULE_CHANNEL_ID}> and verify yourself in <#${process.env.VERIFY_CHANNEL_ID}> to get access to all other channels.`)
                .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor("GREEN")
            ]
        }) 
    }
}
```

In line 13 I get this error. I want to get all online members of the guild and showcase the number in a channel name

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
```

but I it should be working like that if I look into the docs

Comment: presence is a [privileged intent](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents), make sure you have it set up properly

Comment: It is set up properly but for some reason still not working

Comment: Fetch members before accessing to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to fetch the members with [`<Guild>.members.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70463424/14346900).

Example for your case:

```
await member.guild.members.fetch();
var onlineCount = member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
```