# Count number of <tr> in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I just want to count the number of rows,

```
   <button id="add">Add row</button>
<table>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
Number of rows: <span id="counter"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody').after('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        var count = $('#mytbody').children().length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
    });
});
```

I found this [jQuery: count number of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table)

and this doesn't works http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/

I just don't get it working.
help?

Comment: Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/H8sBr/115/ Your code is wrong. You should use `append` instead of `after`.

Comment: Title is bit confusing for the post

Comment: I fix my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The script is wrong, use `append()`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody').append('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        var count = $('#mytbody').children('tr').length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/H8sBr/115/

Answer (score 8):

To get the `tr` *count* using pure js;

```
var count = document.getElementById("mytbody").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/119/)

Comment: Any reason for down vote?

Comment: The script is wrong. :) I will remove the downvote once you correct your answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i don't get it. What is wrong?

Comment: The question is wrong. The script in the question is wrong. See mine and others answers. :)

Comment: My answer is clear, it is giving a count of `tr` Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/117/)

Comment: Well, although the answer is right, this doesn't exactly solve the problem. Does it?

Comment: I don't wanna argue. I also don't like to downvote people. Correct your answer. I have removed the downvote. :) Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, there is no reason you to down vote. There is nothing wrong, count is correct using pure js. and there is nothing to :) either.

Comment: I can say "Sun rises in the east". It is right. Will you downvote? Same reason!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, that is irrelevant. This is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/H8sBr/115/) with my counter.

Comment: Your counter? I don't get you...

Comment: @PraveenKumar, counter is the script which counts trs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25170/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-kaf)

Comment: Same way, your answer is irrelevant...

Comment: @PraveenKumar, how could you decide that. check my fiddle demo in the answer, his problem was counting the trs, and I have given a correct way to count with pure js. I don't understand reason behind your argument.

Comment: The OP's script is wrong. He is using `after()` instead of `append()`. Now do you get it?

Comment: Your fiddle is right man. :) Just saw it. But please mention in your answer about the `append()` stuff... `+1` for you...

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H8sBr/113/).

```
$('#add').bind('click', function () {
    $('#mytbody').append('<tr><td>' + new Date() + '</td></tr>');
    var count = $('#mytbody tr').length;
    $('#counter').html(count);
});
```

You can use simply `$('#mytbody tr').length` but you must also use `append` instead of `after`.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using after(), your code is adding the tr after the #mytbody,

```
<button id="add">Add row</button>
<table>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
    </tbody>
    <tr>Tue Feb 26 2013 23:41:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</tr>
    <tr>Tue Feb 26 2013 23:41:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</tr>   
</table>
```

so when you executing your code

```
$('#mytbody').children().length;
```

it always return you 0.

so instead of after() try to use append() http://forum.jquery.com/topic/after-vs-append

http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/118/

Comment: Actually, not right, but works. So removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `.append()` new `<tr>` nodes, you're inserting them *after* the table body. Use

```
$('#mytbody').append('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#mytbody').append('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        var count = $('#mytbody > TR').length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rectified your JS code. **http://jsfiddle.net/HwEA7/**

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody').append('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        var count = $('#mytbody tr').length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
    });
});
```

1. Use `append` to add row  after `<tbody>`
2. Count number of row as `$('#mytbody tr').length`