# Trouble getting count of table rows that contain certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to output the count of table rows that contain certain text into a label.

When I step through my JavaScript, the count variable initially contains the count, but then ends up with a value of undefined when stepping to the next line.

```
var lblPending = document.getElementById("lblPending");
var count = $("#match-table tr").filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === 'Pending Credit'; }).length;


if (count > 0) {
lblPending.innerHTML = count + " Pending";
}
else {
$("#lblPending").hide();
}
```

Is it the return that would be causing that?

Comment: Jquery has a `.count()` method? Try using `.length` or `.size()` instead

Comment: Can we get a jsfiddle?

Comment: Changed it to `.length` in the example because it has he same behavior. I'll try and replicate in a jsFiddle

Comment: `.length` is not a method

Comment: Just realized, I meant to type "#match-table td" instead of "#match-table tr" :/  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJXJyZ

Comment: Works fine for me. Says '3 Pending'. Unless the td/tr was the problem?

Comment: The td/tr was the problem. Voted to close due to typo

Answer (score 1):

Something like this(using `contains`):

```
$(function(){
   var myRows = $("#match-table tr:contains('Pending Credit')");
   $("#result").html(myRows.length + " Pending");
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/rdesdnqm/