# Javascript to count the number of selected rows in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script to written to check the number of selected rows in a jquery data table. But the count doesn't works. Can anyone help in identifying the bug i made.

I may be silly please excuse and help me out.

```
var table = $("#jobsTable").dataTable();

$('#jobsTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
});

$('#batchAction').click( function () {

    alert("button is clicked");
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').data().length ;

    if( selectedRows === 0){
        alert("Zero rows selected. Please select jobs to proceed with bulk Operation");
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    }

});
```

Comment: do you get any alert?

Comment: Your code isn't very clear. I think you don't need `data()` when counting the rows. There is also a similar question already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table

Comment: `$('#jobsTable').find('tr.selected').length`

Comment: @AmitSoni This works for me !

Answer (score 4):

why just not?

```
$('#jobsTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  alert( $('#jobsTable tbody tr.selected').length + ' row(s) selected' );
});
```

It have to works right. If it is not - call me.

Comment: What count it alert for u? @user3253099

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
```

should be

```
alert( table.rows('.selected').length +' row(s) selected' );
```

That selector would return the number of rows of class "selected"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct, simple way to do it.  Use DT's **count()** function.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

if ( ! table.data().count() ) {  
    alert( 'Empty table' );
}
```

This comes from an example on the data tables website itself, found at https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()