# Echo sum from a table column using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>100</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>200</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>300</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>400</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>500</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>600</td>
</tr><br><br>
<tr>
<td>Total: </td>
<td>2100</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to count and display the total of the column as shown above using PHP but I am not sure how to make this possible. Please help.

Comment: From where the data is coming from? is it coming from any table?

Comment: You want a crawler or sth else?

Comment: You either do it directly with the data which is used to fill that table (preferred way, that data probably is comming from your server) or you use parse the html doc to find the values and them sum them (less efficent way)

Comment: If your table is coming from a php loop you can build a variable $total, set it to 0 before getting into the loop and echo it after the loop has printed the last row. If you are writing it in html directly you need JavaScript and not php. Anyway please post your relevant code please!

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with `javascript` `document.getElementById("idHere").value` and stock the sum of them in a single variable.

The bad part is that you should give every td an Id.

In PHP you should give them `name` attribute, add a `submit` button and get the values from the global-variable `$_POST["nameOfTD"];`

Comment: var count = (int)document.getElementById("firstTD").innerText + (int)document.getElementById("secondTD").innerText + .....; (This is the way if you want to count the Sum of all td's. Do not count the last td as it will have the TOTAL itslef. Assign the count using: document.getElementById("totalCountTD").innerHTML = "<b>" + count + "</b>"; @ShubhamJha

Answer (score -1):

You can use buffer to read the content of the page then parse html:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?><table>
<tr>
<td class="foo">100</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td class="foo">200</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>300</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>400</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>500</td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<td>600</td>
</tr><br><br>
<tr>
<td>Total: </td>
<?php
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML(ob_get_contents());

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');
    function getClass($item) {
        foreach ($item->attributes as $name => $attrNode) {
            if ($name == 'class') {
                return $attrNode->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        $item = $items->item($i);
        if (getClass($item) == 'foo') {
            $sum += intval($item->nodeValue);
        }
    }
    echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
?>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: what if I give a particular td an id? can i then replace it here  $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td'); ?

Comment: how can I use the class name or id name here  $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td'); in place of td ?