# how to count table tbody tr using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

please suggest me 
 my code :

```
$('.Create-New-Order').click(function () {
    var totalRowCount = $("#table_New_Order tbody tr").length;
    alert(totalRowCount);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: count number of rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: Assuming you've included jQuery in the page properly and are running your code when the DOM has loaded, what you have should work. Given that you're trying to use the content of a modal window, I'd guess you need a delegated event handler for the `#Create-New-Order` button

Comment: Put your HTML please

Comment: Once check console if there is any error message, if yes then post here

Answer (score 1):

### On-load table tr count

```js
$(function() {
  $('.Create-New-Order').click(function() {
  var total = $('#mytbl tr').length ;
  alert('tr count = '+ total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1px solid red">
 <tr>
   <th>Name</th><th>Email</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody id="mytbl">
 <tr>
   <td>sfdsd</td><td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>sfdsd</td><td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>sfdsd</td><td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="Create-New-Order">Create-New-Order</a>
```

Comment: OP wants on click of `Create-New-Order`

Comment: what you really want ?