# How to find total tr with a specific class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup. How do I find the number of `tr`s with the class `abc` in the table?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class='abc'>
                <td> i am from bd </td>
                <td> i am from bd </td>
                <td> i am from bd </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is basic jQuery: `$('table > tr.abc').length`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: count number of rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: thanks i got it dear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) to count of total elements as below

```js
alert($("tr.abc").length);
console.log($("tr.abc").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='abc'>
    <td> i am from bd </td>
    <td> i am from bd </td>
    <td> i am from bd </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `length` function for this

```
alert($('tr.abc').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .[length](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log($('tr.abc').length);
        )};
```

Answer (score 0):

**check this fiddle** 
https://jsfiddle.net/ajeshkolakkadan/d41fL4e3/

```
$(function () {
   var rc = $('.mytable tr').length;
   alert(rc)
});
```